# How-To Implement Cross-Browser @font-face Support in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fonts, font-face

I am developing a small rails app to serve fonts to other sites

say a request http://url/fonts/fontname will return woff,eot or ttf font based on the browser type.

This app is working fine in my localhost but not in other ip... I know the problem is something to do with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing restriction but don't know how to solve this....

I am using Mongrel...

Comment: Do you have access to the "other sites" files?

Comment: @knu yeah I can able to access other site file

Comment: @cristian I am using this inside a @font-face CSS so when the request fails it uses fallback font... I checked the result in firefox it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said you have access to the other sites' files.
Well then you just need to add `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *` to your .htaccess file on the targeted websites.

[source](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)

Comment: another thing I tried for security seasons is to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin * in response header